# Haskell readFile: Couldn't match expected type ‘[String]’ with actual type ‘IO String’

Tags: string, haskell, io, ghc, ghci

I am trying to read a file into a function to calculate the frequencies of characters in a file. So I am trying the following:

```
charCount :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
charCount input = M.toList $ M.fromListWith (+) [(c, 1) | c <- input]

calculate :: FilePath -> [(Char, Int)]
calculate fp = do
  c <- readFile fp
  charCount c
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
FileWriter.hs:13:8: Couldn't match expected type ‘[String]’ …
                with actual type ‘IO String’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: c <- readFile fp
    In the expression:
      do { c <- readFile fp;
           charCount c }
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: This is a failing of the GHC error message. The real problem is this: `calculate` cannot return just a list type (specifically `[(Char, Int)]`). You're reading a file, which means you've "infected" the function with IO. The way I think about it is that any function that calls into an IO function also then becomes another IO function. Try instead `IO [(Char, Int)]` for the return type.

Comment: If I change the return type it says `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [(Char, Int)]' with actual type ‘[(Char, Int)]’`

Comment: We've now moved on to failings of Haskell's learning curve. A hint: there is a function with type `a -> IO a`, but it's disguised as `(Monad m) => a -> m a`.

Comment: ^^ @astiefel: if you change `calculate`'s return type to `IO [(Char, Int)]`, you have to `return $ charCount c` because you want the value of the calculation be wrapped in `IO` monad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `calculate` calls the `readFile` function which returns a value wrapped in the `IO` monad the function `calculate` must return a `IO` value too, and the result of the call to `charCount` (a pure computation) has to be `return`ed in order to wrap the `[(Char, Int)]` into a monad.

The next example worked in `ghc 7.10.1`:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

charCount :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
charCount input = M.toList $ M.fromListWith (+) [(c, 1) | c <- input]

calculate :: FilePath -> IO [(Char, Int)]
calculate fp =
    readFile fp >>= \c ->
    return (charCount c)
```